# How many total Merasmissions are there in Scream Fortress 2016?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Team Fortress 2 is reusing the same contract tracking mechanism from last year's Halloween Event (the Gargoyle) and thus it is showing all the completed Merasmissions from last year as well.

They've also removed the total count from the 'Tome of Merasmissions':

[image: TF2 Main Screen showing contract drawer with 28 completed Merasmissions]

To top it off, new missions keep appearing as I complete them, so I don't even know where I'm up to in general.

The [Official Scream Fortress Announcement](http://www.teamfortress.com/screamfortress6/) and [TF2 Wiki](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Scream_Fortress_2016) also do not say how many Merasmissions there are.

How many total Merasmissions are there this year? Is there actually a limit or do they simply continuously spawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [Steam Forum Post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/440/discussions/0/282992646984371529/), the total number of missions which you can obtain is 40, (for both years).
[image: NullPointer's Forum Post]

Comment: Does this mean that if I missed some last year that I can get them again this year?

Comment: I can now confirm: I totaled 39 - I missed one last year and I did not receive it again this year.